# Function that takes integer n and prints pi to n digits using string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I want to print pi to `n` decimal places by passing an integer `n` to the string formatting field. However, this gives me an error. What is the correct way to do this?

My code:

```
from math import pi
def print_pi(n):
    print(("%."+str(n)) % pi)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.2.3.py", line 4, in <module>
    print_pi(5)
  File "1.2.3.py", line 3, in print_pi
    print(("%."+str(n)) % pi)
ValueError: incomplete format
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is cleaner with the new (actually, rather old now) `format` method:

```
>>> fmtstr = "{:.{}f}".format(math.pi, 2)
>>> print(fmtstr)
3.14
>>> fmtstr = "{:.{}f}".format(math.pi, 10)
>>> print(fmtstr)
3.1415926536
```

Nice and neat:

```
>>> def print_pi(n, pi=math.pi):
...     print("{:.{}f}".format(pi, n))
...
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print_pi(i)
...
3
3.1
3.14
3.142
3.1416
3.14159
3.141593
3.1415927
3.14159265
3.141592654
```

Comment: It would always be correct to say that the `format` method is _newer_.

Answer (score 3):

You code is missing the type specifier:

```
from math import pi
import sys 

def print_pi(n):
    print(("%%.%df" % n) % pi) 

print_pi(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: IMO using `sys.argv` in your answer is both unnecessary and distracting.